# Error al seleccionar una imagen de mi galeria desde mi app Flutter con image_picker

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

estoy desarrollando una aplicación con Flutter, actualmente desde un button estoy accediendo a mi galeria, pero cuando selecciono la imagen debería de mostrarme en un widget la imagen seleccionada:

```
return Scaffold(
  key: scaffoldKey,
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Producto'),
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon( Icons.photo_size_select_actual ),
        onPressed: _seleccionarFoto,
      ),
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon( Icons.camera_alt ),
        onPressed: _tomarFoto,
      )
    ],
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            _mostrarFoto(),
            _crearNombre(),
            _crearPrecio(),
            _crearDisponible(),
            _crearBoton(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

El metodo que selecciona la foto

```
_seleccionarFoto() async {

foto = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
  source: ImageSource.gallery
);

if ( foto != null ) {
  // limpieza

}

setState(() {});
```

}

El widget que muestra la foto:

```
Widget _mostrarFoto() {

if ( producto.fotoUrl != null ) {
  return Container();
} else {
  return Image(

    image: AssetImage( foto?.path ?? 'assets/no-image.png'),
    height: 300.0,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,

  );
}
```

}

El seleccionar la imagen vuelve al widget desde dónde se ha presionado el botón para acceder a la galería, pero no muestra ninguna imagen y muestra el siguiente error:

```
"Unable to load asset: /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20200123-WA0049.jpg"
```

Luego de eso la aplicación ya no vuelve atrás, debo reiniciar para que vuelva a funcionar. Agradecería su ayuda, por más mínima que sea, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ese error es debido a que al usar `AssetImage` lo que hace es buscar los assets que tengas precargados en la aplicación, en tu caso no lo es, tu obtienes el `File` del image desde la galería, necesitas usar el widget `FileImage`.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/FileImage/FileImage.html

Algo así

```
image: foto != null? FileImage(foto) :  AssetImage('assets/no-image.png')
```